# Function.prototype on method doesn't pass the this of the object

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

I want to create a prototype for Function class like :
( delay is an example )

```
import { delay } from 'lodash';

export default function(
    this: (...args: any) => any,
    wait: number,
    ...params: [any]
  ): any {
  return delay(this, wait, ...params);
};
```

I've applied it and when I call it from a function it's work well:

```
console.log('render');
console.log.delay(1000, 'delayed render');
```

but when I call it from a method the this isn't pass :

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.consoleLog('render');                      // Test {} render
    this.consoleLog.delay(1000, 'delayed render');  // undefined delayed render
  }
  consoleLog(text) {
    console.log(this, text);
  }
}
```

How can I pass the 'this' cleanly ?

Comment: if you are talking about passing scope then you can do it by adding `.bind(this)` at the end of function call or change the function to function impression.

Comment: ty for your answer, if I add `.bind(this)` to `return delay(this.bind(this), wait, ...params);` it pass the function at this not the parent object. What is function impression ?

Comment: Why not `delay(() => this.consoleLog('delayed render'), 100)`? What's the point to make it less straightforward and much harder to debug way?

Comment: I don't want to import lodash in every files. I want to use the class like they could be. It's like that I want to use js. Yes if I want to escape the problem I could to just use lodash but in big project with 50 import it's easier to use prototype and I never use global. It's a function for function so I want to make it a method for function :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the problem is your delay prototype, it's the context in which the `console.log` under the `consoleLog` method is being invoked.

If you define it like this, you'll see the context you want:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.consoleLog = this.consoleLog.bind(this);
    this.consoleLog('render');                      
    this.consoleLog.delay(1000, 'delayed render');
  }
  consoleLog(text) {
    console.log(this, text);
  }
}
```

I believe what's happening is that `delay` is being called on the context of `consoleLog`, and since `delay` is ultimately calling whatever `this(params)` is with no context (not being accessed via an object -- i.e. `consoleLog('delayed render')` instead of `someObj.consoleLog('delayed render')`), thus `undefined`. I hope that makes sense.

To paint it using a pseudo stacktrace:

```
Normal execution context:
const test = new Test()
test.consoleLog('abc')
-> consoleLog gets called in the context of `test`
-> console.log thus displays `Test` as the object `this` is referring to

Delayed execution context:
const test = new Test()
-> delay gets called with consoleLog as `this`
-> this(params) gets executed (consolLog(params))
-> since consoleLog was not called ON an object (see test.consoleLog above)
its context is undefined in strict mode, thus `console.log(this, text)` will
show `undefined "delayed render"`
```